# Bitmap.createScaledBitmap Changed bitmap not displayed

Tags: android, android-image

In my application, on most devices, I am interested in loading and displaying a bitmap exactly as it exists in the resource file:

```
options.inScaled = false;
backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.demo_frame, options);
```

On certain (small) devices, I want to reduce the size of the bitmap, so I call the following:

```
backgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImage, Scale(backgroundImage.getWidth()), Scale(backgroundImage.getHeight()), false);
```

where the Scale function applies a scaling factor to shrink the image.  The bitmap returned shows me the desired values in the getWidth() and getHeight() functions, but the image is displayed in its original size, i.e. without the scaling factor. I assume this has something to do with the options.inScaled parameter, but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inTargetDensity) did not enlighten me. Can someone give a more detailed explanation of the inScaled parameter, and how I can override it in this case?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the returned bitmap from createScaledBitmap is a different bitmap then the source? If you get a bitmap with new width and height it means it's scaled. How do you display this image?

Comment: As noted, the getWidth() and getHeight() function return the new values, so I assume it's a different bitmap.  I display it with canvas.drawBitmap(...).